# Megane release childlock without button

Tags: locks, renault

I have a 2005 Renault Megane (ie #2 model). The child locking button on the driver side window control panel is broken (will be sourcing one when I find a spare).

In the meantime my childlocks are on, and without the button I can't turn them off.

Is there a way to turn the childlock off manually?

Comment: Perhaps you can remove the fuse which is associated with child locks. Of course, this should only be a temporary solution, and you should pay attention to which other functions the fuse is related to.

Answer (score 1):

not knowing anything specifically about a Megane, you should be able to pull off the get behind the broken button (remove dash or arm rest or wherever the button is) and short the wires together.